# How to add include search path to a subdirectory without ’CMakeLists.txt' in CMake?

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I have a CMake project with a directory structure below:

```
.
├── b.h
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── impl
    └── include
        └── a.h
```

I want to include `b.h` in `a.h` but the CMake cannot find `b.h` in `a.h`. I know it's wrong if I include `a.h` in `b.h` while including `b.h` in `a.h`. However, I'm sure that `a.h` will only be used in files in `test/impl`.

The content of `./CMakeLists.txt` simply adds `test/` as a subdirectory.

The content of `./test/CMakeLists` generates an executable target which used **googletest**.

Is there anyway that I can include `b.h` in `a.h` without adding an extra CMake file in `./test/include`?

**./CMakeLists.txt**

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/*.cpp)

add_library(core SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(core PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(test)
```

**./test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES impl/*.cpp)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  core_test
  ${SOURCES}
)
target_link_libraries(
  core_test
  gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(core_test)

target_include_directories(core_test PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Comment: The command `target_include_directories` adds those include directories which you specify in it. So you may call this command with `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/include` as the last argument, so it will add `test/include` as include directory.

Comment: It seems this is used to include ```a.h``` in ```b.h```. What I want to do is include a file outside(```b.h```) from a file inside(```a.h```). Is there any ideas?

Comment: Well, It seems there is a compromise. I add an cpp file to ```./test/impl``` and include the ```a.h``` in the cpp file. Then ```b.h``` could be found in ```a.h```. However, is it possible not to add an extra cpp file but only modify the CMake file to realize this?